# How to extract the counter number of a reference in a bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, ref

I am in the process of writing up my thesis. There is a figure I included in my writing, which was adapted from a publication that I cited in the thesis, so this reference belongs to one of the entries in the bibliography. I would like to have the counter number of that reference in the caption of the figure. The default citation style I used is achemso.dtx, which has the reference number in superscript. I would like the number to stand out.

For example, I have this reference mentioned in the main text, as "Author et al. have discovered that ... \cite{Author_2000}". In the caption of the figure, if I type "Figure adapted from Ref. \cite{Author_2000}", the compiled output is "Figure adapted from Ref. 69", with "69" in superscript. However I would like the number to be in the main line of the text.

Does anyone have a suggestion, if there is a "get number" command that performs this function?

Comment: `natbib` has `\citenum` to extract only the citation number. Unfortunately, it is not quite clear to me whether you actually use `natbib`. The `achemso` classes load `natbib`, but if you only use the `achemso` bibliography style, you may have to load `natbib` manually. To avoid confusion like this is the future it is a very, *very* good idea to include a short yet compilable example document in your question that shows what you have so far (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). The MWE would show us your bibliography setup and would do away with any doubt about it.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!